# Can't allocate memory for triple pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory

I'm doing a project for school and I have a problem and I can't figure out how to solve it. I'm trying to allocate memory for a triple pointer in a function that I will be able to use it as a 2D array, save data and then use it in a different function. But for some reason I can't use the data once I'm out of the function.

BTW I have to use the variables that is writing in the function (`float m1[ROWS][COLS], float m2[ROWS][COLS], float ***C)`.

```
int mat_mul(float m1[ROWS][COLS], float m2[ROWS][COLS], float ***C)
{
    int i, j, k;

    C = (float ***)malloc(sizeof(float*) * 3);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        C[i] = (float **)malloc(sizeof(float*) * 3); 
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            C[i][j] = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) *3);
        }
    }


        for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                (*C)[i][j] = 0;
                for (k = 0; k < ROWS; k++) {
                    (*C)[i][j] += m1[i][k] * m2[k][j];
                }
            }
        }

        printf_s("%.1f\n", (*C)[0][0]);
}
```

```
    int i,j;
    float Results[ROWS][COLS];
    float Angle1[6], Angle2[6];
    Angle_Reader("data_q.csv", &Angle1, &Angle2);
    Angle_Converter(&Angle1, &Angle2);


    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        float Matrix1[ROWS][COLS] = { {cos(Angle1[i]),-sin(Angle1[i]),L1*cos(Angle1[i])},{sin(Angle1[i]),cos(Angle1[i]),L1*sin(Angle1[i])},{0,0,1} };
        float Matrix2[ROWS][COLS] = { {cos(Angle2[i]),-sin(Angle2[i]),L2*cos(Angle2[i])},{sin(Angle2[i]),cos(Angle2[i]),L2*sin(Angle2[i])},{0,0,1} };
        mat_mul(&Matrix1, &Matrix2, &Results);
    }



    printf_s("\n");

    printf_s("%.1f\n", Results[0][0]);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why would you want to do this? If you have a triple pointer in your parameter list, it is probably meant to be an out parameter where you can place a double pointer. Allocating a triple pointer in your function does not make sense. It will not be visible outside of that function.

Comment: When you call `mat_mul` you don't need to use address of your arrays. The name alone already decays to a pointer. The 3rd parameter is ignored anyway as you immediately throw away `C` and replace with new allocated address.

Comment: I agree with the existing comments, there is nothing in the code shown compelling the need for creating space for _3D matrix_.  Suggestions for this, and other issues offered in answer below.

Comment: Do not cast the value returned by malloc.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    float Matrix1[ROWS][COLS] = { {cos(Angle1[i]),-sin(Angle1[i]),L1*cos(Angle1[i])},{sin(Angle1[i]),cos(Angle1[i]),L1*sin(Angle1[i])},{0,0,1} };
    float Matrix2[ROWS][COLS] = { {cos(Angle2[i]),-sin(Angle2[i]),L2*cos(Angle2[i])},{sin(Angle2[i]),cos(Angle2[i]),L2*sin(Angle2[i])},{0,0,1} };
    mat_mul(&Matrix1, &Matrix2, &Results);
}
```

Should not be in a loop as is.

***Either*** move the declaration above the loop, then in the loop, use index values ( i.e. `Matrix2[i][j]` ) instead of `ROWS, COLS`,

```
float Matrix1[ROWS][COLS] = {0};
float Matrix2[ROWS][COLS] = {0};

//Note: these initializers work only for 3x3 array
//Forcing ROWS == 3 and COLS == 3
float data1[ROWS][COLS] = { {cos(Angle1[0]),-sin(Angle1[1]),L1*cos(Angle1[2])},{sin(Angle1[0]),cos(Angle1[1]),L1*sin(Angle1[2])},{0,0,1} };
float data2[ROWS][COLS] = { {cos(Angle2[0]),-sin(Angle2[1]),L2*cos(Angle2[2])},{sin(Angle2[0]),cos(Angle2[1]),L2*sin(Angle2[2])},{0,0,1} };
 ...
 if(Results)
 {
     for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
     {
        Matrix1[i][j] = data1[i][j];
        Matrix2[i][j] = data2[i][j];
        ...
        mat_mul(&Matrix1, &Matrix2, &Results);
     }
```

***...or*** remove the for loop altogether and modify the `i` and `j` indexes from `Angle1[i]` to hard-coded values eg: `Angle1[0], Angle1[1],...` so that the initializers will populate the 2D arrays.

```
float Matrix1[ROWS][COLS] = { {cos(Angle1[0]),-sin(Angle1[1]),L1*cos(Angle1[2])},{sin(Angle1[0]),cos(Angle1[1]),L1*sin(Angle1[2])},{0,0,1} };
float Matrix2[ROWS][COLS] = { {cos(Angle2[0]),-sin(Angle2[1]),L2*cos(Angle2[2])},{sin(Angle2[0]),cos(Angle2[1]),L2*sin(Angle2[2])},{0,0,1} };
mat_mul(&Matrix1, &Matrix2, &Results);
```

***Regarding creating memory***,  Nothing in your code indicates the need for a 3D array.  As stated in comments, the reason for `float ***C`  in the `mat_mul(., ., float ***C)` function prototype is to accommodate *passing the address* of a 2D matrix ( eg. `&Results` ),  when calling function so that it can be modified.  Even then, it would be an improvement to move the logic necessary to create the memory for that variable into its own function, and allocate the memory *before* it is passed as a variable:

```
 float **Results = Create2D(COLS, ROWS);
 if(Results)
 {
     for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) 
     {
        ...
        ...
        mat_mul(&Matrix1, &Matrix2, &Results);
     }
     //When finished using, free Results
     free2D(Results, COLS)
```

The functions `Create2D()` and its companion could be implemented as:

```
float ** Create2D(int c, int r)
{   
    float **arr;
    int    y;

    arr   = calloc(c, sizeof(float *));
    for(y=0;y<c;y++)
    {
        arr[y] = calloc(r, sizeof(float));    
    }
    return arr;
}

void free2D(float **arr, int c)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<c;i++)
    {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```